# Eclipse Plug-in: Content Assist Proposal Info with HTML Format

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

I'm extending eclipse jdt's content assist, 
and I wrote a class that implements IJavaCompletionProposalComputer,
and my code is like the following:

```
final static String[] fgProposals = { "A", "B" }; 
final static String[] fgInfo = { "<font color='red'>A_info</font>", "B_info" };

@Override
public List<ICompletionProposal>
computeCompletionProposals(ContentAssistInvocationContext context, IProgressMonitor monitor) {
  ICompletionProposal[] result = new ICompletionProposal[fgProposals.length];
  for (int i= 0; i < fgProposals.length; i++) {
    IContextInformation info = new ContextInformation("AA", "BB");
    result[i]= new CompletionProposal(
        fgProposals[i], context.getInvocationOffset(), 0,
        fgProposals[i].length(), null, fgProposals[i],  
        info, fgInfo[i]);   
  }
  return Arrays.asList(result);
}
```

However,
the additional info (the window at the right of the selected proposal) 
ignores html tags and just shows plain text.

My question is the same as this topic:
[HTML Formatting in Editor ContentAssit](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t64764.html)
I've read this,
but I can't understand the explanation they said.

Could anyone tell me how to solve this question with a clearer explanation?
A simple code snippet will help a lot!!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple code snippet is not possible because this is not simple!

Instead of your code returning an array of `CompletionProposal` you must return an array of classes that implement both `ICompletionProposal` and `ICompletionProposalExtension3`.

One of the extra methods in `ICompletionProposalExtension3` is

```
public IInformationControlCreator getInformationControlCreator()
```

This must return an `IInformationControlCreator` class. This class just has one method:

```
public IInformationControl createInformationControl(Shell parent)
```

The returned `IInformationControl` is the class that displays the proposals and can deal with HTML. There is a abstract class `AbstractInformationControl` which implements some of the basic requirements but it is down to you to deal with the HTML.

One way to deal with the HTML is to use the SWT `Browser` widget. There is a `BrowserInformationControl` which does this but it is in the **internal** package `org.eclipse.jface.internal.text.html` so it is not available for use by plugins.

Comment: Thank you very much!! Your answer helps a lot for me. I used DefaultInformationControl and it worked,
but it only supports very small simple html tags. I'm looking for the method that can support more html tags.